# Audio not playing in android. android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-resources

I am trying to play an audio file in Android but it seems to crash and give a the `ResourcesNotFoundException`. The audio file is saved in the raw folder inside res. The name of the audio file is determined by a randomly generated number which is then concatenated to "audio".

```
int res = getResources().getIdentifier ( "audio"+arrayIndex, "raw","com.din.askak" );
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create ( MainActivity.this, res );
```

In the logcat it seems to throw the exception on the line creating the mediaPlayer. I don't know what I seem to be doing wrong???

Comment: thanks; I got that working with `context.getPackageName()` and wrote my tweak to KDEConnect app up here: https://twitter.com/Pen_Bird/status/1674925800108494848

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of `getIdentifier()` function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier rather than by name.

Comment: my `R.raw.chimp` didn't work

Answer (score 0):

on https://invent.kde.org/network/kdeconnect-android my `R.raw.chimp` didn't work, so I went with this in `PingPlugin.java`:

```
    ...
    NotificationManager notificationManager = ContextCompat.getSystemService(context, NotificationManager.class);

    if ("error".equals(message)) {
        int res = context.getResources().getIdentifier("chimp", "raw", context.getPackageName());   //  Mmmmm. Raw chimp! --Homer Simpson
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this.context, res); //  R.raw.chimp);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NotificationHelper.Channels.DEFAULT)
            .setContentTitle(device.getName())
    ...
```

my tests take 27 minutes, so I programmed KDE-Connect's Android app to scream like a chimp when they fail, to alert me from across the house so I can run back to my workstation and fix the tests.

I added the file ./build/dependency-license-res/raw/chimp.wav , then my tests call `kdeconnect-cli --device BLAHBLAH  --ping-msg "error"`