# MediaPlayer: Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-mediaplayer

I am developing an Android app with MediaPlayer, SQLite, and more stuff. I need to play a mp3 file with MediaPlayer depending on the user choice in the database. I reviewed  [Audio not playing in android. android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472518/audio-not-playing-in-android-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-r), but there is nothing useful. When I tried to start the activity that contains MediaPlayer, there is appearing this exception:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                                 at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
                                                 at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.openRawResourceFd(ResourcesImpl.java:287)
                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:1267)
                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:931)
                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:914)
                                                 at com.primerosauxilios.udec.appprimerosauxilios.vista.activities.CasoAMostrarActivity.onCreate(CasoAMostrarActivity.java:53)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

This is my code:

**Caso.java**

```
package com.primerosauxilios.udec.appprimerosauxilios.logica;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Created by daniel on 3/10/17.
*/

public class Caso {

private int id;
private String nombre;
private String procedimiento;
private ArrayList<String> palabrasClaveBusqueda;
private String nombreAudioProcedimiento;

public Caso(){

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public void asignarProcedimiento(String procedimiento){
    this.procedimiento = procedimiento;
}

public String getProcedimiento(){
    return procedimiento;
}

public void asignarAudioAProcedimiento(String nombreAudio){
    this.nombreAudioProcedimiento = nombreAudio;
}

public String getAudioProcedimiento(){
    return this.nombreAudioProcedimiento;
}


public void agregarPalabraClave(String palabraClave){

}

public boolean eliminarPalabraClave(String palabraClave){
    return false;
}

public boolean esPalabraClave(String palabraClave){
    return false;
}
}
```

**CasoAMostrarActivity.java**

```
package com.primerosauxilios.udec.appprimerosauxilios.vista.activities;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.primerosauxilios.udec.appprimerosauxilios.R;
import com.primerosauxilios.udec.appprimerosauxilios.logica.Aplicacion;
import com.primerosauxilios.udec.appprimerosauxilios.logica.Caso;
import com.primerosauxilios.udec.appprimerosauxilios.persistencia.DatabasePAConstantes;

public class CasoAMostrarActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private TextView tvTexto;
private String nombreCaso;
private Caso caso;
private MediaPlayer reproductor;
private ImageButton btnRetrasar, btnPlayPause, btnAdelantar;
private double tiempoComienzo = 0, tiempoFinal = 0;
private int tiempoAdelante=5000, tiempoDetras=5000;
private boolean reproduciendoAudio;
private SeekBar barraProgreso;
private Handler manejador;
private static int unTiempo = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_caso);

    tvTexto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTexto);
    nombreCaso = getIntent().getStringExtra(DatabasePAConstantes.CASO);

    cargarCaso();

    btnPlayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlayPause);
    btnAdelantar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAdelantar);

    Resources recursos = getApplicationContext().getResources();

    int archivo = getResources().getIdentifier(caso.getAudioProcedimiento().toLowerCase(),
                                                "raw",

    getApplicationContext().getPackageName());//Se obtiene el id del archivo mp3

    reproductor = MediaPlayer.create(this, archivo); // Se carga el 
    audio en el objeto MediaPlayer

    barraProgreso = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.barraProgreso);
    barraProgreso.setClickable(false);
    reproduciendoAudio = false;
    manejador = new Handler();

}
```

Like you can see, the exception is generated from line 53 of CasoAMostrarActivity.java.

> reproductor = MediaPlayer.create(this, archivo);

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

**Ad hoc Solution**

```
 String audio = caso.getAudioProcedimiento().toLowerCase();
 audio = audio.substring(0, audio.length()-4); //With this, I delete the extension .mp3 from string audio
 int archivo = getResources().getIdentifier(audio,"raw", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

 reproductor = MediaPlayer.create(this, archivo);
```

Comment: Looks like whatever `caso.getAudioProcedimiento().toLowerCase()` is returning isn't a valid raw resource name.

Comment: Dima Kozhevin and there is nothing useful. That's why I made this post.

Comment: Mike M I added toLowerCase() at then end of the sentence because the names of the files are in lowercase. Then, I wanted to be sure that there would be not a names error.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but there's nothing else we can help you with, from the given information. We have no idea what resources are available in your `raw/` folder, nor what `caso` is, or what its `getAudioProcedimiento()` method is returning there.

Comment: Mike M getAudioProcedimiento() returns an string that contains the name of the mp3 file in raw folder.

Comment: Well, your `Resources` disagrees. Do some debugging to see what exactly `caso.getAudioProcedimiento()` is returning there.

Comment: I have done some debugging to caso.getAudioProcedimientos() and there is returning the name of the file next to the name of the file extension, something like "filename.mp3". That's the way the filename is stored in database. Now, at runtime there is staying something like this: 

`int archivo = getResources().getIdentifier("filename.mp3","raw",getApplicationContext().getPackageName());`

Comment: Is this right, Mike?. Raw folder contains .mp3 files.

Comment: No, you need to drop the extension. Just `"filename"`, no `".mp3"`.

Comment: I deleted the file extension in the values of column archivoAudio in table Casos. There is from I am getting the filename. Still not working. The method `caso.getAudioProcedimiento()` still returning `filename.mp3` instead of just `filename` . Then, I just tried this solution and it worked. Look at my update of the post.

Comment: Yeah, that'll work, obviously, but you should really find out why it's still returning that filename with the extension, if you've indeed changed it in the database. Well, glad you got it working, for now, at least. Cheers!

Comment: Yes. At least for now. Thanks, bro.

Comment: Sorry very much, but this is not a duplicate of nothing existing in this site. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862322/how-to-find-resource-id-of-a-file-located-in-res-raw-folder-by-its-filename not consits about ResourcesNotFoundException.

Comment: You're getting the `Resources$NotFoundException` because you're passing `0` to that `MediaPlayer` method, and that post explains why you're getting that `0` value. If you had actually read your stack trace and done a little research, you would've known to ask why you get `0` there.